# How to find elements on one column for values in other columns having no more than 3 gap in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I have an sql view say `emp_table` which looks like the following:

```
+----------+----------+------+
| actor_id | movie_id | year |
+----------+----------+------+
|        2 |   280088 | 2002 |
|        2 |   396232 | 2000 |
|        3 |   376687 | 2000 |
|        4 |   336265 | 2001 |
|        5 |   135644 | 1953 |
|        6 |    12083 | 1996 |
|        7 |   252053 | 1993 |
|        7 |   402635 | 1992 |
|        7 |   409592 | 1995 |
|        8 |   101866 | 2000 |
|        9 |   336265 | 2001 |
|       10 |    12148 | 2000 |
|       11 |    80189 | 2001 |
|       12 |    12148 | 2000 |
|       13 |    80189 | 2001 |
|       14 |    70079 | 1982 |
|       15 |    12148 | 2000 |
|       16 |   242675 | 1991 |
|       17 |   105231 | 1993 |
|       17 |   242453 | 1988 |
+----------+----------+------+
```

... and so on.  I need to find all the `actor_id` who never had a career gap of more than 3 year. Meaning I need to calculate all the actors for whom if I calculate the number of unique years they acted in a movie, and then sort it, then the maximum consecutive difference between the year would never be more than 3 years.
Please help me with this sql query. I have tried sql self join but couldn't think more about it.

All the SQL code is for MySQL only.

**Note** You can consider that there is only one combination of actor_id and movie_id.

**Expected Result**

```
+----------+----------+
| actor_id | max_gap  |
+----------+----------+
|        2 |   2      |
|        3 |   0      |
|        4 |   0      |
|        5 |   0      |
|        6 |   0      |
|        7 |   2      |
|        . |   .      |
|        . |   .      |
|        . |   .      |
|       17 |   5      |
+----------+----------+
```

And so on

**Note 2:** Sorry for so many changes in the output. This is the final version and no more change after this.

Comment: With that table data, what is the expected result?

Comment: I think this is a gaps and islands problem.  Having MySQL 8 available would be helpful here.  Gordon Linoff will post an answer when he does his daily cleanup.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I have MySQL 8

Comment: Why actor_id = 7 has max_gap = 3 and actor_id = 2 has max_gap = 1?

Comment: @forpas Thanks for mentioning..Edited the question

Comment: actor_id = 2 must have max_gap = 2

Comment: Also actor_ids = 8,9,10,...,16 are not included in your expected results why?

Comment: @No for actor_id = 2, gap would be 1 not 2. I wrote so on...

Comment: if 2000 to 2002 for actor_id = 2 is gap = 1 then 1993 to 1995 for actor_id = 7 should give gap = 1 too.

Answer (score 2):

I initially started with an anti-join approach, but then changed it upon seeing your requirement for the max gap.

The approach below begins with a subquery which itself uses a correlated subquery to compute the forward looking year gap, for every actor record and year.  It then aggregates by actor and asserts that a gap greater than 3 years never occurs.

```
SELECT actor_id, MAX(gap) AS max_gap
FROM
(
    SELECT
        e1.actor_id,
        ABS(e1.year - COALESCE((SELECT e2.year FROM emp_table e2
                       WHERE e2.actor_id = e1.actor_id AND e2.year > e1.year
                       ORDER BY e2.year LIMIT 1), e1.year)) AS gap
    FROM emp_table e1
) t
GROUP BY
    actor_id
HAVING
    MAX(gap) <= 3;
```

Note that the call to `COALESCE` is very necessary, because of the edge case of an actor's most recent year.  In this case, there is no forward looking year, but we want to discount this year.

Comment: What will happen to an actor playing four years in a row?

Comment: He would be included in the result set, the max gap in that case being 3 years.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Great solution. So you basically have taken all the year combinations for an actor and subtracted the rest of the year and itself and taken the absolute value. So if ever there is a gap > 3, it would show up in `MAX(gap)`. Pretty ingenious.

Comment: Sorry @TimBiegeleisen I guess if a person is acting 4 years in a row, we can have max gap being 3 years. The gap would be 0 years. I am afraid this yields wrong results.

Comment: @MayukhSarkar You're making me work bro!  Edited my answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The `ORDER BY` would be `Ascending` by default. Are you sure about it??

Comment: @MayukhSarkar Yes.  Read through the logic.  I'm saying to take all years _greater_ than the year for the current actor record.  Then, order it ascending (the default, as you correctly pointed out), and keep the _first_ year.  Well, this must be the very next adjacent year (except for the greatest year, q.v. the comments in my answer).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Why this must be the very next year. I mean the person whose current year is 2000 then the next year may not be 2001, it may be 2007 also. Moreover how some `NULL` values are occurring??

Comment: We are checking every gap in the actor's record.  This means taking each year and computing the distance to the next _nearest_ year.  Regarding NaN values, that doesn't exist in MySQL.  I made a slight change to my use of `COALESCE`; you may try the updated query.

Comment: You need to change `t1.year` to `e1.year`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Perhaps unbeknownst to you, I did all this work on a cell phone, with no real ability to test anything.

Answer (score 2):

With *MySQL 8* and *MariaDB 10.2* you can use the *window function* [`LEAD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead) to get the next consecutive playing year for an actor (or `LAG()` for the last one). Then you just need to get the max difference in the outer query.

```
with tmp as (
  select 
      actor_id,
      year,
      lead(year) over (partition by actor_id order by year) as year_lead
  from emp_table e
)
select actor_id, coalesce(max(year_lead - year), 0) as max_gap
from tmp
group by actor_id
having max_gap <= 3;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cWChT2TqLuRT8bW1zcM9G2/0

Comment: And it's about time that MySQL begin to support the analytic functions +1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen After soooooo many years they even [support the CHECK constraint](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3464) now ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A self join of the table and the group by actor_id:

```
select
  e1.actor_id, max(coalesce(e2.year, e1.year) - e1.year) max_gap
from emp_table e1 left join emp_table e2
on 
  e2.actor_id = e1.actor_id
  and 
  e2.year = (
    select min(year) from emp_table where actor_id = e1.actor_id and year > e1.year
  )
group by e1.actor_id  
having max_gap <= 3
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3ZVinC8G8fxRdyzeMPUkUN/0)